# Can't click Menu Bar Items in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, macos

I just opened up ADT (eclipse) today and I had this issue where I couldn't click any item in the menu bar above the program.

I'm running Mac OSX 10.9 Mavericks Dev Preview

Here's a screen shot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/umZOG.png

Things I've tried.
Restarting Program,
Restarting Computer,
Reinstalling ADT from scratch, and tirelessly googling the issue.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Try the Mac dev forum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest Mavericks preview messes up Java - I had the same issue. Fix it by installing this: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US