# App can't be opened because it is from an unidentified developer

Tags: eclipse, osx-mavericks

I installed Mac OS X Mavericks (10.9) yesterday and since then I am not able to start my Eclipse. I am attaching a screenshot of the message I see.

Is there a workaround for this?

[image]

I found a solution in *[Fix the “App can’t be opened because it is from an unidentified developer” Error in Mac OS X](http://osxdaily.com/2012/07/27/app-cant-be-opened-because-it-is-from-an-unidentified-developer/)*.

Comment: Related: *[Installing Java on OS X 10.9 (Mavericks)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19533528)*

Comment: Check this out for step by step instructions http://y2u.be/heUv6RtFtrI

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Mac Applications and not programming.  It would be better suited on http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Steve. Eclipse has nothing to do with programming? That's news to me. Installing the tools of the trade seem to me a viable question for Stack Overflow. I'm more concerned about the OP not selecting a correct answer (nudge, aghem, cough Chandan).

Comment: See the **xattr alternative** below for **locked down security settings**

Answer (score 363):

It's because of the Security options.

Go to `System Preferences... > Security & Privacy` and there should be a button saying `Open Anyway`, under the `General` tab.

You can avoid doing this by changing the options under `Allow apps downloaded from:`, however I would recommend keeping it at the default `Mac App Store and identified developers`.

Comment: I don't think this is new in Mavericks.

Comment: @bamboon You are right; I must have lowered my security level ages ago and forgotten about it. I will update my answer.

Comment: Actually, we can right click on Eclipse icon and choose Open without change Security Policy. Follow here: http://osxdaily.com/2012/07/27/app-cant-be-opened-because-it-is-from-an-unidentified-developer/

Comment: In 10.8.5, the option to select from the 'Allow applications downloaded from:' set of radio buttons is: 'Anywhere'

Comment: The "Control-click/Open" method is much safer.  This opens your system to any app from wherever.  Do not surrender this much control!

Comment: @mpemburn I don't understand what you mean; I recommend leaving the security at the default "Mac App Store and identified developers".

Comment: There's no option for 'Open Anyway' in Yosemite but you can select 'Open All'.

If the option is greyed out click the lock icon on the bottom right first and authenticate with your login password.

Answer (score 123):

An easier way to open a document from an unidentified developer, if you know it's safe, is to control-click on the file icon and then select "Open." You will then be given the option of opening it regardless of its unidentified source.

Answer (score 33):

Right-click (or control-click) the application in question and choose "Open"

Answer (score 33):

In terminal type the command:

```
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine [file path here]
```

Once you click enter it will no longer have that problem. Its annoying that apple adds a quarantine to files automatically. I do not know how to turn this off but there probably is a way...

Comment: Thank you! This solved a problem with two apps that would get blocked at startup (running macOS Sierra). One (AwakenHelper) was saying "the identity of the developer cannot be confirmed." The other was saying "Tonido.app is damaged and can't be opened."

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I tried control-click from Finder etc. to no avail. But this worked.

Answer (score 20):

You can also use the `xattr` command as in Stack Overflow question *[How do I remove the "extended attributes" on a file in Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833052)*.

Just remove the `com.apple.quarantine` attribute. It works even if you don't have an administrator account, which can be a plus. After that, the app isn't considered "downloaded" and is therefore not blocked.

Comment: This works if you have locked down security preferences e.g. on an **Enterprise Mac**.
cd /Applications/eclipse/
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine Eclipse.app

Answer (score 8):

It is prohibiting the opening of Eclipse app because it was not registered with Apple by an identified developer. This is a security feature, however, you can override the security setting and open the app by doing the following:

1. Locate the Eclipse.app (eclipse/Eclipse.app) in Finder. (Make sure you use Finder so that you can perform the subsequent steps.)
2. Press the Control key and then click the Eclipse.app icon.
3. Choose **Open** from the shortcut menu.
4. Click the **Open** button when the alert window appears.

The last step will add an exception for Eclipse to your security settings and now you will be able to open it without any warnings.

Note, these steps work for other *.app apps that may encounter the same issue.

Answer (score 8):

you can modify the gatekeeper settings by running the following command

To disable to allow apps from anywhere to be installed use the following command in terminal ::

> sudo spctl --master-disable

To re-enable use the following command

> sudo spctl --master-enable

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, Eclipse would not start. Found this link and it worked like a charm:

[Can't click Menu Bar Items in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413900/cant-click-menu-bar-items-in-eclipse)

Java is messed-up on Maverick, need to download and install from here:
http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

Answer (score 4):

Control Click the application in the Applications folder, not lauchpad. Choose open and then you get  an options to actually open it.

Answer (score 4):

I had got the same error. 
Because of security reasons, I could not see option for *allowing Apps downloaded from Anywhere* in System preference-> Security Tab.

I removed the extended attribute from Zip file by below command.

```
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine [Zip file path]
```

And then got below error:-
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct

Resolved it by uninstalling all different versions of java and installed just 1.8.0_231.

Worked finally.

Answer (score 3):

Right click > Open.

Or, you can go into System Preferences, Security & Privacy, and set the restrictions on opening apps there.

Answer (score 3):

Terminal type:

```
Last login: Thu Dec 20 08:28:43 on console
 ~  sudo spctl --master-disable
Password:
 ~  spctl --status
assessments disabled
 ~ 
```

System Preferences->Security & Privacy

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In your terminal, simply run

```
sudo spctl --master-disable
```

in order to allow apps be downloaded from any developer

Comment: This just repeats cryptonkid's answer from 2017, without the instruction for how to turn it back on again. Permanently disabling this security feature is obviously a risk many users will not be prepared to take.

Answer (score 2):

Open terminal, go to extracted folder of eclipse and run the following command:

```
./eclipse -clean
```

Answer (score 1):

On MacOS Ventura 13.5, after running an app which is being blocked, it will show up in the Privacy & Security section in preferences, where you can press on 'Allow Anyway' to disable it.

[image: MacOS System Preferences (Privacy & Security)]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34770995)

Answer (score -1):

Open Terminal, Go to the eclipse folder, Run ./eclipse

Answer (score -2):

Try looking into Gatekeeper. I am not sure of too much Mac stuff, but I heard that you can enable it in there.