# Firefox Marketplace Mac Unidentified Developer

Tags: macos, firefox, osx-mavericks, mozilla

We have an app on the Firefox Marketplace. When a user installs it (and the FF marketplace) by default, a Mac shows the FF Marketplace app as coming from an unidentified developer. Is there any way to solve this from an app builders perspective. I know the users way:

[App can't be opened because it is from an unidentified developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19551298/app-cant-be-opened-because-it-is-from-an-unidentified-developer)

But I'd like to know if the FF Marketplace knows/has a way to get around this. Many of our (and FF) users will not proceed beyond that.

Thanks!

Comment: Any success? I have the same problem.