# How to install eclipse in mavericks 10.9?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, osx-mavericks

I installed `eclipse` for java developers from this link:**https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/?osType=macosx**

and now it shows these error in opening:
`Eclipse" can't be opened because it is from an unidentified developer`.
What should I do now, and from which link I should download it,( as I thought that this one is official link for `eclipse`)?

Comment: That is the official Eclipse site but Eclipse does not sign the application with an Apple developer's certificate so you get this message. See http://osxdaily.com/2012/07/27/app-cant-be-opened-because-it-is-from-an-unidentified-developer/ for how to deal with it

Comment: hahahaha! a lot of people ask for the same ! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19551298/app-cant-be-opened-because-it-is-from-an-unidentified-developer

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+click in your app inside finder and from the menu choose "Open"...

or

Go to `System Preferences` > `Security & Privacy` and click the option `Open Anyway`